# Google Apps Script「スクリプトにはその操作を行う権限がありません。」のエラーにつきまして

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Scriptで GmailApp.sendEmail メソッドを実行すると

スクリプトにはその操作を行う権限がありません。

その操作を行うには
「(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/)」権限が必要です。

とエラーが出てしまいます。
つい昨日までは問題なく実行できていたのですが、本日急に上記のエラーが出ました。

色々調べてみたのですが原因がわかりません・・。
どなたかお詳しい方何卒ご教授ください。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 突然deprecatedになったのかと思いましたが、2018/09/05時点では普通にドキュメントに存在しますね…… https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

昨日から同様な状況になった者です。
原因はよく理解できていないのですが、以下のいずれかの方法で回避できましたのでお知らせします。

＜その1＞
GmailApp.sendEmail 
を
MailApp.sendEmail  
に変更。

＜その2＞
【GAS】GmailAppに対するマニフェスト設定
https://qiita.com/hisayuki/items/725110707d8abc8796d8
を見ながらマニフェストを修正して対応

お試しください。